# Can Flow and Mortar load a screen in the background if it is slow to load (e.g. GoogleMap)?

Tags: android, mortar, square-flow

I am having trouble with certain pages in an Android app loading slowly. I have fixed many by pushing the slow parts into services that preempt the user's requirements.

I am struggling with GoogleMaps, which are slow to load at around 5 seconds on a recent Android phone. Does Square's Mortar and Flow system allow preloading in the background? Can I get my views filled in the background on a Blueprint and then bring them to the foreground?